# GPL 2.0 лицензия. Пропустят ли меня в App Store?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Здравствуйте, вот тут ходят слухи по инету что мое приложение могут развернуть, из-за наличия в нем субпроекта на GPL лицензии версии 2.0.
Кто-нибудь сталкивался в последнее время с такой траблой?

Comment: Сам не сталкивался, но тоже читал в интернетах что проблемы с подобными продуктами, но пруф так и не видел.

Если ответа не найдется и у вас появятся данные по этому поводу, то просьба поделиться.

Comment: Ок. Тогда попробуем пробиться. Если, что отпишусь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, это возможно, в случае если всё приложение лицензировано лишь под GPL и не содержит других лицензий. Связано это с тем, что политика распространения приложений в App Store противоречит положениям самой GPL.